# How to proof HALT doesn't reduce to L?

Tags: halting-problem

What method(s) can I use in general to proof HALT doesn't reduce to given language?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, show that $L$ is decidable, mostly by designing an algorithm to decide it.

Comment: What if L is not decidable like "Consistent Guessing"?